# C# -Application hang after connected with IP Camera

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am developing an application to show video using webcam and IpCamera.
For `IpCamera`, it shows video stream for sometime but after that it stops streaming and application hangs.

I am using [Emgu.CV Library](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php?title=Camera_Capture) to grab frames and show it in the picture control.

I have tried below code for display of video by using function `QueryFrame()`.

for connecting Ip camera
`Capture capture = new Capture(URL);`

for grabbing frames
`Image<Bgr, Byte> ImageFrame = capture.QueryFrame();`

After some time the `QueryFrame()` provide `null` value and application hangs.

Can any one tell me why this is happening and how I can handle it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the error that is reported when the app hangs? If it's your code, do you have a stack trace that can provide more details?

Comment: I have edited the question. But till now no error has been shown.

Comment: Are you doing anything with ImageFrame after if so you want to incase it if an if(ImageFrame != null) statement. Else a try{}catch(nullExc eption ex){} may address the problem however I would advise against it if possible. Cheers

Comment: @Chris my code is in `try catch` block but there is no exception for the same

Comment: Sorry I was typing in a rush 'NullReferenceException' should be work if not use catch(Exception ex) and see what type of Exception is thrown. But if not can you post the code causing the problem so I can debug it it properly. Cheers

Comment: @Chris Please take a look on my another [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21745309/3110262).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry about the delay but I have provide an example that works with several public IP cameras. It will need the EMGU reference replacing with your current version and the target build directory should be set to "EMGU Version\bin" alternatively extract it to the examples folder.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/emguexample/files/Capture/CameraCapture%20Public%20IP.zip/download

Rather than using the older QueryFrame() method it uses the RetrieveBgrFrame() method. It has worked reasonably well and I have had no null exceptions. However if you do replace the  ProcessFrame() method with something like this

```
private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
{
    //If you want to access the image data the use the following method call
    //Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = new Image<Bgr,byte>(_capture.RetrieveBgrFrame().ToBitmap());

    if (RetrieveBgrFrame.Checked)
    {
        Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = _capture.RetrieveBgrFrame();
        //because we are using an autosize picturebox we need to do a thread safe update
        if(frame!=null) DisplayImage(frame.ToBitmap());
    }
    else if (RetrieveGrayFrame.Checked)
    {
        Image<Gray, Byte> frame = _capture.RetrieveGrayFrame();
        //because we are using an autosize picturebox we need to do a thread safe update
        if (frame != null) DisplayImage(frame.ToBitmap());
    }
}
```

Cheers

Chris

Comment: Thanks for your answer but on `_capture = new Capture(URL)` it is throwing error `System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled Emgu.CV.Dll`

Comment: Hi sorry the libraries are for x64 system please replace them with x86 libraries if this is the version of EMGU you are using and ensure that the platform target of the project is set accordingly