# IP Camera stop streaming after some time

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, ip-camera

I am working on one application where I want to use `IP camera` for displaying video streaming and and some other major operations on image captured by the `IP Camera`.

**Libraries used in Camera capture**
For Camera Capture : [Emgu.CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php?title=Camera_Capture) Library

Below is the code which I am using in C#.

*Variable Declaration*

```
    private Capture capture;        //takes images from camera as image frames
    private Emgu.CV.UI.ImageBox img; // Dynamic Picture Controls
    private int nCam;               // no of cameras
```

*Code for Processing Image*

```
  private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
  {
    try
          {                
      // Live Streaming Display
     Image<Bgr, Byte> ImageFrame = capture.QueryFrame();

    // If Ip camera try to reinitialize the IP camera
    if(ImageFrame == null)
   {
       capture.Dispose();
       capture = new Capture(URL);                              
        ImageFrame = capture.QueryFrame();
     }                
      ImageFrame = ImageFrame.Resize(img.Width, img.Height, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR); 

     img.Image = ImageFrame;

    // Here I am doing some other operations like 
    // 1. Save Image captured from the IP Camera
    // 2. Detect faces in Image 
    // 3. Draw Face markers on Image
    // 4. Some database based on result of Face Detection
    // 4. Delete image File 
    // continue Looping for other Ip Cameras        

     }
      catch (NullReferenceException e)
       {
       }
    }
```

Now, The Problem is after some time the `QueryFrame()` provide `null` value and camera Stop streaming.

Can any one tell me why this is happening?
How I can resolve this problem?
If any more information is needed Please Let me know.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you passing random value in URL like URL + "?Random()". This will refresh and return you very recent image. please try this lets see if it work?

Comment: @Nil23 can you please give some more hint like at which place in URL I should put this `?Random()` ?

Comment: at the end of URL you will have to put "?6" like any random number with question mark as prefix

Comment: @Nil23 I am using Public IP to connect IP camera so because of that `?6` it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about the delay but I have provide an example that works with several public IP cameras. It will need the EMGU reference replacing with your current version and the target build directory should be set to "EMGU Version\bin" alternatively extract it to the examples folder.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/emguexample/files/Capture/CameraCapture%20Public%20IP.zip/download

Rather than using the older QueryFrame() method it uses the RetrieveBgrFrame() method. It has worked reasonably well and I have had no null exceptions. However if you do replace the  ProcessFrame() method with something like this

You should not be attempting to do any operations if the frame returned is Image is a nullable field and should not have a problem if  _capture.RetrieveBgrFrame(); returns null if there is a problem then there is a bigger issue.

```
private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
{
    //If you want to access the image data the use the following method call
    //Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = new Image<Bgr,byte>(_capture.RetrieveBgrFrame().ToBitmap());

    if (RetrieveBgrFrame.Checked)
    {
        Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = _capture.RetrieveBgrFrame();
        //because we are using an autosize picturebox we need to do a thread safe update
        if(frame!=null)
        { 
             DisplayImage(frame.ToBitmap());
             Image<Bgr, Byte> ImageFrame = frame.Resize(img.Width, img.Height,  Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR); 

             // Here I am doing some other operations like 
             // 1. Save Image captured from the IP Camera
             // 2. Detect faces in Image 
             // 3. Draw Face markers on Image
             // 4. Some database based on result of Face Detection
             // 4. Delete image File 
             // continue Looping for other Ip Cameras  
        }
        //else do nothing as we have no image
    }
    else if (RetrieveGrayFrame.Checked)
    {
        Image<Gray, Byte> frame = _capture.RetrieveGrayFrame();
        //because we are using an autosize picturebox we need to do a thread safe update
        if (frame != null) DisplayImage(frame.ToBitmap());
    }
}
```

On a separate note your comment 'continue Looping for other Ip Cameras' may cause several issues. You should have a new **Capture** constructor for each camera camera you are using. How many camera are you using? and what public ip camera are you using so I can attempt to replicate the issue? The reason for the separate constructor is that ip cameras take a while to negotiate connections with and constantly Disposing of the original construct and replacing it will play havoc with the garbage collector and introduce no end if timing issues.

Cheers

Chris

[EDIT]

If your camera is returning null frames after a timeout period then I would check to see if there is an issue with the setup or maybe your connection is so slow it disconnects you to reduce lag to others there are various causes but this is not a code problem. You can use c# alone to acquire the data to a bitmap and then pass this to an Image type variable. There is a great article here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15537/Camera-Vision-video-surveillance-on-C

I've adapted this so you can use a HttpWebRequest as a final check to see if the stream is alive although there are still null exceptions that will be produced here:

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

string url;

    private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {
        //***If you want to access the image data the use the following method call***/
        //Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = new Image<Bgr,byte>(_capture.RetrieveBgrFrame().ToBitmap());

        if (RetrieveBgrFrame.Checked)
        {
            Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = _capture.RetrieveBgrFrame();
            //because we are using an autosize picturebox we need to do a thread safe update
            if (frame != null)
            {
                DisplayImage(frame.ToBitmap());

            }
            else
            {
                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                // get response
                WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
                //get stream
                Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
                if (!stream.CanRead)
                {
                    //try reconnecting the camera
                    captureButtonClick(null, null); //pause
                    _capture.Dispose();//get rid
                    captureButtonClick(null, null); //reconnect
                }
            }
        }
        else if (RetrieveGrayFrame.Checked)
        {
            Image<Gray, Byte> frame = _capture.RetrieveGrayFrame();
            //because we are using an autosize picturebox we need to do a thread safe update
            if (frame != null) DisplayImage(frame.ToBitmap());
        }
    }

    private void captureButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        url = Camera_Selection.SelectedItem.ToString(); //add this
        ... the rest of the code
    }
```

To display multiple webcams you would create a class to handle the Capture construct and processframe event. Ideally you would raise an purpose built event call that would include a camera identifier as the frameready event call does not call this. I have to make things easier created a form with as a MDI  parent and opened an object to manage the capture variables and frame ready event. The Alpha version is available here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/emguexample/files/Capture/CameraCapture%20Public%20IP%20Multipl%20Display%20Alpha.zip/download

Comment: Thanks for your answer but on `_capture = new Capture(URL)` it is throwing error `System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled Emgu.CV.Dll`

Comment: Hi sorry the libraries are for x64 system please replace them with x86 libraries if this is the version of EMGU you are using and ensure that the platform target of the project is set accordingly

Comment: thanks, But there is also one problem that when I am doing some other tasks which I have mentioned in my Question by `Comments` The Camera returns `null` `ImageFrame`.

Comment: I appreciate that but I think your missing the points of the code that are important I will edit it to try and make it clearer. The 'Image' type is nullable fine but you shouldn't be attempting any operation if it is null if(frame!=null){ do tasks } //else do nothing cheers

Comment: yeah that's right but the problem is if `frame == null` then what should I do and my camera streaming is getting stopped.

Comment: If your camera streaming is getting stopped this is not your code but an issue with camera. If a null frame is returned the general practice is to simply show nothing and wait until the next frame is sent. If the camera is disconnecting you then there is an issue with the camera set up or it is designed to stop continuous streaming. I've added a bit more to the answer

Comment: Actually I am want to use multiple IP cameras so for that I am not able to use `capture[nCam
].ImageGrabbed += ProcessFrame` so is there any other way to get it done.

Comment: Hi see the updated alpha version but you could create a class to store capture and process frame event instead I created on object/form to do the same.http://sourceforge.net/projects/emguexample/files/Capture/CameraCapture%20Public%20IP%20Multipl%20Display%20Alpha.zip/download Cheers