# Emgucv return null Image for QueryFrame for IP Camera

Tags: c#, opencv, camera, emgucv

I am working on one application where I want to use `IP camera` for displaying video streaming and and some other major operations on image captured by the `IP Camera`.

**Libraries used in Camera capture**
For Camera Capture : [Emgu.CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php?title=Camera_Capture) Library

Below is the code which I am using in C#.

*Variable Declaration*

```
    private Capture capture;        //takes images from camera as image frames
    private Emgu.CV.UI.ImageBox img; // Dynamic Picture Controls
    private int nCam;               // no of cameras
```

*Code for Processing Image*

```
  private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
  {
    try
          {                
      // Live Streaming Display
     Image<Bgr, Byte> ImageFrame = capture.QueryFrame();

    // If Ip camera try to reinitialize the IP camera
    if(ImageFrame == null)
   {
       capture.Dispose();
       capture = new Capture(URL);                              
        ImageFrame = capture.QueryFrame();
     }                
      ImageFrame = ImageFrame.Resize(img.Width, img.Height, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR); 

     img.Image = ImageFrame;

    // Here I am doing some other operations like 
    // 1. Save Image captured from the IP Camera
    // 2. Detect faces in Image 
    // 3. Draw Face markers on Image
    // 4. Some database based on result of Face Detection
    // 4. Delete image File 
    // continue Looping for other Ip Cameras        

     }
      catch (NullReferenceException e)
       {
       }
    }
```

Now, The Problem is after some time the `QueryFrame()` provide `null` value and camera Stop streaming.

Can any one tell me why this is happening?
How I can resolve this problem?
If any more information is needed Please Let me know.

It is a duplicate Question of [IP Camera stop streaming after some time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21745309/3110262).

But, I was unable to get answer by this question.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @Chris yes it is Actually I was not able to get the answer at that time on This question so I did this and thanks for your answer Posted on these all questions.

Comment: Hi Ankit thats fine I'm just flagging it so it can be removed 
Cheers,