# creating multiple threads of a function

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, emgucv

I am working on one project where I stuck on one point where I have to run two methods in parallel.

**In Function 1**

In my application what I am doing is I am grabbing images from the IP cam and storing that image into the one folder.
This function is used for continues streaming of camera.

For this you can refer this question which I have asked [IP Camera stops streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21745309/3110262).

**In Function 2**

I will pick images from the path where my *Function2* is dumping images.

Here I am doing some other operations like:

1. Save Image captured from the IP Camera
2. Detect faces in Image
3. Draw Face markers on Image
4. Some database based on result of Face Detection
5. Delete image File

*Function 2* takes more execution time than *Function 1*.

So for this purpose after searching on google I get to know I can do this by multithreading.

So, I am little bit confused about this and as I am new in c# I am not that much aware of multithreading.

So, can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Please, do not include a languge tag in a title unless it wouldn't made sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek Ok, I will take care from next time

Comment: The best help you can get is read tutorials on multithreading - there are plenty of them. Topic of this site is solving particular implementation problems, not providing introductory courses - they already exist on the internet.

Comment: @BartoszKP Actually i have gone through some tutorials but getting confused that how can I call the tread multiple times

Comment: user47381 answers your question... whenever you wish to call the thread function, just call "Function 1" like he described. It is a minimalist example, but it illustrates well the way to go.

Comment: Multithreading is all about [th-reading](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) =D

Comment: @AnkitB Then present a particular case you don't understand with a concrete code sample. Don't just ask about "helping out" and "I'm new". Consider reading the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 2):

You do indeed need to use multithreading, and in your case it should not be too difficult.

You'll need to add a "using System.Threading;" to the start of any files that involve threading.

```
public void Function1()
{
    //Do camera stuff

    Image image = MagicalCameraStuff();

    //Create a thread that the processing will occur on
    Thread process = new Thread(() => Function2(image));
    //Start the thread
    process.Start();
}

public void Function2(Image i)
{
    //Do some processing without blocking the main thread
}
```

More information on threading:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But while performing this operations in a loop I am getting message dialog as `Cross Thread Operation is not valid`. Can you help me on this